# TCP Client Reading

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcp, tcpclient

Using vb.net I am trying to setup a simple app to open a tcp session to a host, write some data, read some data, then write some more and read some more.

I can get it to write and read - but only once.. what am I doing wrong here. The second attempt to readline just times out. Using Telnet I can make it work no problem but there is something I am doing wrong here with the tcp client.

There error I get is:

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

```
        Dim client As New TcpClient(server, port)
        client.SendTimeout = 2000
        client.ReceiveTimeout = 4000

        'CONNECT
        Dim message As String = "HELLO"
        Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(stream)

        'WRITE THE DATA
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = Convert.ToString(reader.ReadLine())
        If Not responseData.ToUpper.Contains("READY") Then
            Return responseData
        End If

        message = "OPTION"
        'WRITE THE DATA
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        responseData = Convert.ToString(reader.ReadLine())
        If Not responseData.ToUpper.Contains("READY") Then
            Return responseData
        End If

        ' Close everything.
        stream.Close()
        client.Close()
```

Comment: What is the server expecting?  Should you be sending something to let the server know that the client data is complete - e.g. perhaps it expects the client messages to be CRLF terminated?  Maybe try `Dim message As String = "HELLO" & vbCrLf` and `message = "OPTION" & vbCrLf`.

Comment: I am getting data back on the first read - and the second write works... it is when I read the second time from the string that it hands.

Comment: Showing a sample telnet session in your question may make things clearer.  Perhaps the server is writing something as soon as you connect, and this is what you are reading... i.e. it may be unrelated to the data you are sending, and not an indication that you are sending anything that the server is expecting.

Comment: ha ha I believe you are actually on to the proper answer here. I am sorry. THank you for your help I will report back in a bit.